# Curved closed arrow

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to write `$id:G\to G$` in the form of `$:id:G\circlearrowleft$` but in fact I want this arrow: [image]

Comment: Special case of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

[image]

Note the use of `\colon` instead of `:` for proper spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{id}\colon G\;\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\circlearrowleft$}$
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the `MnSymbol` package has the arrow `\rcirclearrowleft`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{id}\colon G\rcirclearrowleft$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, tyvm!

Comment: Interestingly, the `MnSymbol` also seems to replace the `\colon` by a shifted variant